# Location Access Denied using Leaflet and Local Host

Tags: javascript, express, leaflet

I am having issues with the locate function in leaflet.

I am using express to serve my app over local host. It works when I access it from my own computer, but when I use a different computer on the network it denies location access.

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to network and permissions. Any help would be appreciated!

App.js for express

```html
var express     = require("express"),
    app         = express(),
    router      = express.Router(),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/plugins"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("app is running on port " + port);
});
```

Index.js:

```html
    mymap.locate({setView: true})
      .on("locationfound", function(e){
        if(currentLoc){
          currentLoc.remove();
          currentLocErr.remove();
        }
        currentLoc = L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup('Your location');
        currentLocErr = L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy/2, {
            weight: 1,
            color: 'blue',
            fillColor: '#cacaca',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
          });
        mymap.addLayer(currentLoc);
        mymap.addLayer(currentLocErr); 
      })
      .on("locationerror", function(e){
        alert("Location access denied.");
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-locate):

> locate(< Locate options > options?): Tries to locate the user using the Geolocation API ... Note that, if your page doesn't use HTTPS, this method will fail in modern browsers

So what happens in your case, is that your localhost is a reliable source and your browser will let you use the Geolocation API which is provided by the browser itself, with no problem.

However, if you are trying to access it from another computer in your network you should publish your code as HTTPS in order for it to work correctly, otherwise it's going to throw the error you are getting.

you can read more about the Geolocation API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

Comment: Thank you, I just figured this out. I've never had to do that before but it's all working now using SSL.